# React-Native: Change opacity colour of ImageBackground

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, imagebackground

I have been trying to develop screen mentioned below:

For that I have created below component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image} from 'react-native';
import Balance from './Balance.js'

class AccountHeader extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('../images/lawrance.jpg')}
                style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.overlay}></View>
                    <Text style = {[styles.textStyle, {paddingTop: 10}]} >My Account</Text>
                    <Image source= {require('../images/lawrance.jpg')}
                        style={styles.avatarStyle}/>
                    <Text style = {styles.textStyle} > Jenifer Lawrance</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.textStyle} > +14155552671</Text>
                    <Balance style= {styles.balanceContainer}/>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor:'red',
        opacity: 0.6
    },
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor:'transparent',
        opacity: 0.6
    },
    avatarStyle: {
        width:100, 
        height: 100,
        marginTop: 10,
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    textStyle: {
        marginTop: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    balanceContainer:{
        padding:10,
    }
  });

export default AccountHeader;
```

Now here are two issues:

1. Changing the opacity of `ImageBackground` also change the opacity of its children
2. Not able to change the color of opacity

Any help appreciated!

> **Design screen:**

[image]

> **Developed Screen**

[image]

Comment: Did you tried removing the container's opacity ? As per the given style, the container also contains opacity value, thus entire container is getting affected.

Comment: @ rohan kangale : Yeah. But I want to apply opacity at background image.

Comment: backgroundColor="rgba(32,36,100,0.6)" use background color like this

Comment: @ Paras Watts: Not working at all! Please note it is 'ImageBackground' not Image

Comment: Try to move your Image outside your ImageBackground(you will need to change style as well).

Comment: @ rohan kangale: I have used that component so I can use image as background image!

Comment: Try with zIndex. Make sure the Image's zIndex value to be greater than the overlay's and container's zIndex.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use this code, it's working, I just made a minor change

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image,Dimensions} from 'react-native';

class AccountHeader extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ImageBackground
                source={{uri:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSoOVTmb0ILbDI6ggGhPKUkn3v4UKc2dNB-Kjng7aGM14UbvzKY'}}
                style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style = {[styles.textStyle, {paddingTop: 10}]} >My Account</Text>
                    <Image source= {{uri:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSoOVTmb0ILbDI6ggGhPKUkn3v4UKc2dNB-Kjng7aGM14UbvzKY'}}
                        style={styles.avatarStyle}/>
                    <Text style = {styles.textStyle} > Jenifer Lawrance</Text>
                    <Text style = {styles.textStyle} > +14155552671</Text>
                    </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}     

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {

},            
overlay: {
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
},
    avatarStyle: {
        width:100, 
        height: 100,
        marginTop: 10,
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    textStyle: {
        marginTop: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "#FFFFFF",
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    balanceContainer:{
        padding:10,
    }
  });

export default AccountHeader;
```

Comment: This is a magical line:
backgroundColor:'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',

Comment: Yep, this line worked for me too, thanks for the update

Comment: Yep. You usually want to overlay a dark background with opacity like done here, and not change the opacity of the picture it self. This creates a good contrast to put text over.

Answer (score 75):

Try this :

```
<ImageBackground source={require('./images/backgroundBlue.jpg')} imageStyle= 
{{opacity:0.5}}/>
```

it works

Comment: This is really the correct answer, thank you very much :)

Comment: This one solved the problem  imageStyle=  {{opacity:0.5}}

Answer (score 11):

For me worked just applying some opacity to the ImageBackground component and at the same time a background color like this:

```
<ImageBackground source={background} style={{ width: window.width, height: window.height - 24, backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,0,0)' }} resizeMode="cover" imageStyle={{opacity: 0.4}} >
</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the container's style to

```
container: { 
 backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,.6)'
},
```

Comment: this function is not supported with my react-native function. Also will children get opacity given here?

Comment: this work for me some opacity in imagebackground not child