# React Native Opacity from Parent to Child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

I am `ImageBackground` with `opacity: 0.6` in the styles. This wraps my other components. This opacity has led to reduce the opacity of the child components. How to override the style in child components like a `View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scene is that you cannot override the `Opacity` attribute. But for achieving what I want I followed what this guy had to say

> [React-Native: Change opacity colour of ImageBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399114/react-native-change-opacity-colour-of-imagebackground)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use opacity. Use it in background color props like this -

> backgroundColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the style in the child component by applying a style to it in that file. The style applied the latest is the one given priority. For example, the below will render in blue color.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const stylesA = {
  color: "red"
};

const stylesB = {
  color: "blue"
};

const B = () => <div style={stylesB}>hey there</div>;

const A = ({ children }) => (
  <div style={stylesA}>
    <B />
  </div>
);

render(<A />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vm6o1jx49l

Comment: This doesn't help. This is an example for ReactJS. I am asking for React Native.

Comment: It works the same for React Native. Also, your code at the link doesn't run because you can't use React Native components on the web unless you're using something like react-native-web. You need to post all relevant code here.

Comment: Fine. I was just trying to show the code. Well, I am doing this for Opacity. Maybe opacity does not work in this case.